# Multiple GridLines of different colors

Tags: plotting, style, grid-lines

I wanna plot 2 gridlines in colors. One in red. Other in blue. How to do it?

Wrong code:

```
Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 1}, GridLines -> {{0.25, 0.5}, {}}, GridLinesStyle -> {{ {Red, Blue}}, {}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look at ref / GridLines / Details, you can just use `GridLines -> {{{0.25, Red}, {0.5, Blue}}, {}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
GridLinesStyle -> {{Red},{ Blue}}
```

As described [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GridLinesStyle.html).

Comment: This does not work in v11.2.0

Answer (score 9):

The previous solutions no longer seem to work (in v11.2.0).
However, you can style each gridline individually inside `GridLines` like so:

```
Plot[
    {x, x^2}, {x, 0, 1}, 
    GridLines -> {
        {{0.25, Red}, {0.5, Blue}}, 
        {}
    }
]
```

Any additional styling in `GridLinesStyle` will also apply and override. Note this includes the default styling (seems to be lowered opacity) if you don't specify `GridLinesStyle`!